# Activity doesn't receive Broadcast from IntentService

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to send a broadcast from IntentService to Activity, but it doesn't work, even the Service did send the broadcast ( I check by debugger tool ).

The strange thing is that I have few other service that broadcast but only this particular one doesn't work.

Here is my code:

IntentService:

```
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myItent = new Intent ("test");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

BroadcastReceiver in MainActivity:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver testbcreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "succeed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("success");
    }

};
```

onResume, where I register the BroadcastReceiver. Note that I have 4 service here, 2 out of 4 work fine.

```
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mds.open();
    registerReceiver(testbcreceiver, new IntentFilter("test"));

    registerReceiver(downloadServiceReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            DownloadChapterService.NOTIFICATION));

    registerReceiver(parsingMangaReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            ParsingMangaLinkService.NOTIFICATION));

    registerReceiver(parsingMangaChapterReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            ParsingChapterMangaService.NOTIFICATION));
}
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name="anvu.bk.service.ToastService">
    </service>
```

Thank you for looking at my question.

Comment: Have you added onReceive method on your Activity do like this :public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
           public static final String ACTION_RESP =
              "mypackagename.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";

           @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// TODO Start a dialogue if message indicates successfully posted to server
            }
    }

Comment: I believe I already have that part of code posted in the question. Please check it :).

Comment: Well, I solved the problem. Turn out that I forget to update the new "action" name for the intentfilter. Thank you everyone. :D

Answer (score 2):

Change it

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myItent = new Intent ("test");

    sendBroadcast(intent);
    System.out.println("wait");

}
```

To

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myItent = new Intent ();
    myItent .setAction(DownloadChapterService.NOTIFICATION); // Define intent-filter
    sendBroadcast(myItent );
    System.out.println("wait");

}
```

Comment: Woops, that wasn't the original code. Thank you for pointing that out. The problem is still unsolved thought. 
*edit: I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your intent to be broadcast, prefix your action with your package name and set it like this:

```
public static final String TEST_ACTION = "anvu.bk.service.TEST_ACTION";

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Intent myItent = new Intent ();
    myIntent.setAction(TEST_ACTION);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Then, in your onResume(), register your receiver:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

//basically, we need the same string as when we were preparing intent for broadcast
//so set action this way, or use string "anvu.bk.service.TEST_ACTION" instead
//of course, use the class name where you declared TEST_ACTION :)
filter.addAction(IntentService.TEST_ACTION); 

registerReceiver(testbreceiver, filter);
```

Then remember to unregister your receiver in onDestroy() with:

```
unregisterReceiver(testbreceiver);
```

As a side note, don't use System.out.println() - use Android's Log.d() to log things. [Here's why](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html):

> System.out.println() (or printf() for native code) should never be used. System.out and System.err get redirected to /dev/null, so your print statements will have no visible effects. However, all the string building that happens for these calls still gets executed.

Comment: It turns out that I decided to change the name of the action at one point, but forget to update it in the Activity. Thank you! You did help me solve the question.